# 2d array nearest point coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

i´m struggling with this issue for like 3 weeks now;
i´ve a board (2d array):

```
0   0   0   -1  0   0   0   0   0   0
0   -1  0   0   0   0   0   -1  0   0
0   0   0   0   -1  0   0   0   -1  0
0   0   -1  -1  -1  0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -1  -1
```

where `-1` represent bombs and I have to create a function `nearest_bombs(board, x,y):` that give me the nearest bomb coordinates when the user puts x,y coordinates, for example in this case:

User input:

```
x = 0
y = 0
```

Value to be returned: `(1,1)`

For now I already made location of the bombs in the board:

```
def where_bombs(board): 
    bombs = board
    result = np.where(bombs == -1)
    bombsCoordinates= list(zip(result[0], result[1]))
    return bombsCoordinates

x=0
y=0
```

and the calculation of the nearest one:

```
def near_bomb(board,x,y):
    b = [(x,y)]
    a = where_bombs(board)
    from scipy.spatial import distance
    dist = distance.cdist(a, b, 'euclidean')
    print (min(dist))
```

But I´m struggling how to return the coordinates for the near distance, in that case the near bomb should be `(1,1)`.

Comment: Hey @nytrous - welcome to SO! To improve your question could you make it reproducible? I.e. someone should be able to copy the code in your question and immediately be able to reproduce your problem and start working on a solution. E.g. where is the `board` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the last line in `near_bomb()` to use `np.argmin()`:

```py
def near_bomb(board,x,y):
    b = [(x,y)]
    a = where_bombs(board)
    from scipy.spatial import distance
    dist = distance.cdist(a, b, 'euclidean')
    print (a[np.argmin(dist)])
```

`argmin` returns the argument (the index) of the value that is the minimum, which you can then use to access the corresponding coordinate in `a`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Pure Python implementation representing what's happening in the code above.

```
import math 
import sys

def get_euclidean_dist(start_coord, end_coord):
  """
  start_coord, end_coord is tuple in form (x,y)
  """
  return math.sqrt((end_coord[0]-start_coord[0])**2+(end_coord[1]-start_coord[1])**2)

def get_bomb_coords(board):
  """
  Get each bomb location as a list of tuples.
  Each tuple represents the location of a each bomb.
  """
  r = []
  n_rows = len(board)
  n_cols = len(board[0])
  for i in range(n_rows):
    for j in range(n_cols):
      if board[i][j]==-1:
        r.append((i,j))
  return r

def get_nearest_bomb(user_location, bomb_locations):
  """
  Get nearest bomb for given user location.
  """
  nearest_bomb_coord = None
  last_min_distance = sys.maxsize
  for bl in bomb_locations:
    location_from_user = get_euclidean_dist(user_location, bl)
    if location_from_user<last_min_distance:
      last_min_distance = location_from_user
      nearest_bomb_coord = bl
  return nearest_bomb_coord

if __name__ == "__main__":
  board = [[0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0],
            [0, 0, -1, -1 ,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1]]
  bomb_coordinates = get_bomb_coords(board)
  user_location = (0,0)
  nearest_bomb_from_user = get_nearest_bomb(user_location, bomb_coordinates)
  print(nearest_bomb_from_user)
```